# While containerizing web app , it gets stuck at copying war file

Tags: java, maven, docker, spotify-docker-client

```
[INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:1.0.0:build (default) @ bookstore ---
18:35:34.921 [main] DEBUG com.spotify.docker.client.DockerCertificates - /root/.docker/ca.pem, /root/.docker/key.pem or /root/.docker/cert.pem does not exist, not using SSL
18:35:35.076 [main] DEBUG com.spotify.docker.client.DockerConfigReader - Using configfile: /root/.dockercfg 
[WARNING] No entry found in settings.xml for serverId=docker-hub, cannot configure authentication for that registry
[INFO] Using authentication suppliers: [ConfigFileRegistryAuthSupplier]
[INFO] Copying /home/ales/Git/BookStore/target/bookstore-1.war -> /home/ales/Git/BookStore/target/docker/bookstore-1.war
```

i am trying to containerizing the java web app (which i have got from web as a sample) , i am using **maven** to build app and using **spotify** plugin to convert war to dockerimage.

when i run `mvn clean package docker:build` it gets stuck copying step  and doesn't proceed further.

**Note: my project name is Bookstore.**

This is the error that issued after a long run of copy command ,

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) @ bookstore ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [bookstore] in [/home/ales/Git/BookStore/target/bookstore-1]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/ales/Git/BookStore/WebContent]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [110 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/ales/Git/BookStore/target/bookstore-1.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:1.0.0:build (default) @ bookstore ---
23:31:08.311 [main] DEBUG com.spotify.docker.client.DockerCertificates - /home/ales/.docker/ca.pem, /home/ales/.docker/key.pem or /home/ales/.docker/cert.pem does not exist, not using SSL
23:31:08.567 [main] DEBUG com.spotify.docker.client.DockerConfigReader - Using configfile: /home/ales/.docker/config.json
[WARNING] No entry found in settings.xml for serverId=docker-hub, cannot configure authentication for that registry
[INFO] Using authentication suppliers: [ConfigFileRegistryAuthSupplier]
[INFO] Copying /home/ales/Git/BookStore/target/bookstore-1.war -> /home/ales/Git/BookStore/target/docker/bookstore-1.war
[ERROR] Java heap space -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/OutOfMemoryError
```

Comment: Permissions problems I think, you are running docker as root it seems: `Using configfile: /root/.dockercfg` but trying to read the war from your user space. There's no need to run as root and in fact is not advisable. Setup docker to be able to run as user and go from there.

Comment: your answer is sounding good to me and it seems like you have got the root of problem , but again as a newbie i will say , may you provide me , what steps to do to solve this problem? or provide me link of article which refer to this problem. Thanks a lot , you are helping me securing my career.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

Comment: may you help me a bit , actually what i am doing is i build my app with mvn , i issue command on terminal and i use STS IDE for coding purposes , but what problem i am encountring is when i try to clean the project it is unable to clean the target folder and when i run the same command with sudo  then it run , but in cost of that only root gets the full control of the folder , i think that is why it stucks on copying instruction. What can be the possible solution to this ?

Comment: Aye , i have resolved that permission issue , just used chmod command on target directory and yeah it went nice. But it still stucks at copying step.

Comment: You are on the track :p, that's how fixing problems and learning works. Give some time to learn Linux fundamentals, it's a must on backend stuff.

Comment: I will learn it soon , but i am in second round of competition(TCS InfraMind) and the deadline is 11 Oct and i have to do a lot of work (even tho i am stuck at the first step) , thats why ican't give too much time to learn a technology now all i am trying to do is just making my way to go through all of the required technologies.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz , may you try to build my web app and see if it run on your machine or not  , here is the [Github](https://github.com/ales-blaze/BookStore.git)  link to it.

Comment: What's current status? Still the same [OutOfMemory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/OutOfMemoryError)?

Comment: @Luis build success , thankyou so much for helping out!

Comment: Glad to be of help.